# What is sufficient in proving iff statement

Tags: proof-verification, logic, proof-writing

I'm very new to writing proofs and I'm wondering if the following is sufficient for a proof of an if and only if statement

Suppose *x, y* $\in \Bbb{R}$. 
Then $x^3+x^2y=y^2+xy$ if and only if $y=x^2$ or $y=-x$.

This is of the form $P\iff(Q\vee R)$. 
We begin by proving $(Q\vee R)\Rightarrow P$.

Case 1: Assume $y=x^2$.

Then $x^3+x^2y=y^2+xy$ becomes $x^3+x^2(x^2)=(x^2)^2+x(x^2)$, which becomes $x^3+x^4=x^3+x^4$ which is obviously true.

Case 2: Assume $y=-x$.

Then $x^3+x^2y=y^2+xy$ becomes $x^3+x^2(-x)=(-x)^2+x(-x)$ which becomes $x^3-x^3=x^2-x^2$ which is obviously true.

Now proving $P\Rightarrow (Q\vee R)$:

Assume $x^3+x^2y=y^2+xy$.

Then we have $x^2(x+y)=y(x+y)$ which becomes $y=x^2$

$\therefore P\Rightarrow (Q\vee R)$ and so $P\iff(Q\vee R)$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: You can do that operation the last step only when $x+y=0$. If it is equal to zero, you get your second case. That is the complete proof

Comment: You meant $x+y\ne0$.

Comment: This seems rather elaborate. The equation is equivalent to $(x^2-y)(x+y)=0$ which is true iff $x^2-y=0$ or $x+y=0$.

Comment: ahhh yes thank you!